# How to use dynamic branching to skip unnecessary instructions

Tags: if-statement, optimization, shader, branch, hlsl

I would like to use dynamic branching to skip unnecessary instructions. Please consider two functions:

```c
float computeFirst(float s)
{
    [branch] if(abs(s) > 1.0)
        return -1.0;
    
    // a bunch of instructions
    
    return acos(s); // acos just for example
}

float computeSecond(float s)
{
    [branch] if(abs(s) > 1.0)
    {
        return -1.0;
    }
    else    
    {
        // a bunch of instructions
        
        return acos(s); // acos just for example
    }
}
```

Are these functions equivalent? Both have the dynamic branch but do they work the same way and the unnecessary instructions are actually skipped (when all the pixels in a warp follow the same branch)?

Using *Shader Playground*, I found that these two functions compile differently:

```
// computeFirst
ps_5_0
dcl_globalFlags refactoringAllowed
dcl_input_ps linear v0.x
dcl_output o0.xyzw
dcl_temps 2
lt r0.x, l(1.000000), |v0.x|
if_nz r0.x
  mov r0.y, l(-1.000000)
endif 
add r0.z, -|v0.x|, l(1.000000)
sqrt r0.z, r0.z
mad r0.w, |v0.x|, l(-0.018729), l(0.074261)
mad r0.w, r0.w, |v0.x|, l(-0.212114)
mad r0.w, r0.w, |v0.x|, l(1.570729)
mul r1.x, r0.z, r0.w
mad r1.x, r1.x, l(-2.000000), l(3.141593)
lt r1.y, v0.x, -v0.x
and r1.x, r1.y, r1.x
mad r0.z, r0.w, r0.z, r1.x
movc o0.x, r0.x, r0.y, r0.z
mov o0.yzw, l(0,0,0,0)
ret 
// Approximately 17 instruction slots used

// computeSecond
ps_5_0
dcl_globalFlags refactoringAllowed
dcl_input_ps linear v0.x
dcl_output o0.xyzw
dcl_temps 2
lt r0.x, l(1.000000), |v0.x|
if_nz r0.x
  mov r0.x, l(-1.000000)
else 
  add r0.y, -|v0.x|, l(1.000000)
  sqrt r0.y, r0.y
  mad r0.z, |v0.x|, l(-0.018729), l(0.074261)
  mad r0.z, r0.z, |v0.x|, l(-0.212114)
  mad r0.z, r0.z, |v0.x|, l(1.570729)
  mul r0.w, r0.y, r0.z
  mad r0.w, r0.w, l(-2.000000), l(3.141593)
  lt r1.x, v0.x, -v0.x
  and r0.w, r0.w, r1.x
  mad r0.x, r0.z, r0.y, r0.w
endif 
mov o0.x, r0.x
mov o0.yzw, l(0,0,0,0)
ret 
// Approximately 18 instruction slots used
```

In *computeFirst*, dynamic branch looks useless and never seems to allow unnecessary instructions to be skipped. Am I misunderstanding something and are these two compiled versions equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the *computeFirst* function is better optimized without the branch attribute. I just added the actual expressions instead of the comment line and now the compilation result depends on the number of instructions that can be skipped using dynamic branch:

```cpp
float computeFirst(float s)
{
    if(abs(s) > 1.0)
        return -1.0;
    
    s = acos(s) / acos(-1.0);
    s = acos(s) / acos(-1.0);
    s = acos(s) / acos(-1.0);
    s = acos(s) / acos(-1.0);
    s = acos(s) / acos(-1.0); // if you comment out this line, dynamic branching will not be used
    
    return s;
}
```

```
ps_5_0
dcl_globalFlags refactoringAllowed
dcl_input_ps linear v0.x
dcl_output o0.xyzw
dcl_temps 1
ge r0.x, l(1.000000), |v0.x|
if_nz r0.x
  add r0.x, -|v0.x|, l(1.000000)
  sqrt r0.x, r0.x
  mad r0.y, |v0.x|, l(-0.018729), l(0.074261)
  mad r0.y, r0.y, |v0.x|, l(-0.212114)
  mad r0.y, r0.y, |v0.x|, l(1.570729)
  mul r0.z, r0.x, r0.y
  mad r0.z, r0.z, l(-2.000000), l(3.141593)
  lt r0.w, v0.x, -v0.x
  and r0.z, r0.w, r0.z
  mad r0.x, r0.y, r0.x, r0.z
  mul r0.y, r0.x, l(0.318310)
  mad r0.z, -r0.x, l(0.318310), l(1.000000)
  sqrt r0.z, r0.z
  mad r0.x, r0.x, l(-0.005962), l(0.074261)
  mad r0.x, r0.x, r0.y, l(-0.212114)
  mad r0.x, r0.x, r0.y, l(1.570729)
  mul r0.x, r0.z, r0.x
  mul r0.y, r0.x, l(0.318310)
  mad r0.z, -r0.x, l(0.318310), l(1.000000)
  sqrt r0.z, r0.z
  mad r0.x, r0.x, l(-0.005962), l(0.074261)
  mad r0.x, r0.x, r0.y, l(-0.212114)
  mad r0.x, r0.x, r0.y, l(1.570729)
  mul r0.x, r0.z, r0.x
  mul r0.y, r0.x, l(0.318310)
  mad r0.z, -r0.x, l(0.318310), l(1.000000)
  sqrt r0.z, r0.z
  mad r0.x, r0.x, l(-0.005962), l(0.074261)
  mad r0.x, r0.x, r0.y, l(-0.212114)
  mad r0.x, r0.x, r0.y, l(1.570729)
  mul r0.x, r0.z, r0.x
  mul r0.y, r0.x, l(0.318310)
  mad r0.z, -r0.x, l(0.318310), l(1.000000)
  sqrt r0.z, r0.z
  mad r0.x, r0.x, l(-0.005962), l(0.074261)
  mad r0.x, r0.x, r0.y, l(-0.212114)
  mad r0.x, r0.x, r0.y, l(1.570729)
  mul r0.x, r0.z, r0.x
  mul r0.x, r0.x, l(0.318310)
else 
  mov r0.x, l(-1.000000)
endif 
mov o0.x, r0.x
mov o0.yzw, l(0,0,0,0)
ret 
// Approximately 47 instruction slots used
```